# k8s service name can not reslove in browser

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I want to send request using service name(*.svc.cluster.local) from outside the kubernetes cluster.

### Now I use openVPN in cluster, and I can connect to it.And I can use service cluster IP to access service. To reslove the service name, I config the VPN to push a DNS server, and nslookup can parse the service name correctlly. But when send request from browser, *.svc.cluster.local can not be resloved. It seems that request do not send to the configured DNS server.I'm so confused, need help!

I push a private DNS server address, problem solved.

Comment: Can you try curl from command-line or postman to see whether it is only the browser that is affected? Have you tried different browsers? If it is browser only that is affected there are some suggestions that could be relevant in https://superuser.com/questions/512241/how-to-set-custom-dns-server-for-chrome-browser and https://superuser.com/questions/65382/does-chrome-use-a-different-dns-server-from-firefox-and-ie-which-use-the-os-defa

Comment: In order to help others, please, consider to do two things: a) check your question and improve your spelling, b) instead of including the answer in your question use the answer button of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I use private IP instead of public IP in 'push "dhcp-option DNS xxx.xx.xx.xx"' in server.conf. After restart openvpn, problem sloved!